# Discord reply to user`s message via request

Tags: python, discord, request

is it possible to reply to user's message with post request?
I don't want to use discord.py, because I need to use my account, not bot.

I used something similar to the code below, but it is mention, not reply.

```py
msg = f"@{user} " + choice(list) + choice(symbols)
```

By reply I mean this: [reply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewe3z.png)

Comment: Umm, kind of. But as @Pythonwolf mentioned, it's against the terms of service, and you should not violate them. If you want to automatically reply to messages, just resort to discord bots.

Answer (score 0):

Self-botting is againt the [Discord TOS](https://discord.com/terms), read more [here](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-)